# Building a package that runs tests needing X server (debuild)

Tags: apt, packaging, debuild

I'm trying to make a package for [srsGUI](https://github.com/srsLTE/srsGUI) a package for drawing plots. Its tests require X server to run. Everything seems to build fine, then it gets to the tests and spits out:

```
$ debuild -us -uc
...
1/8 Test #3: realplot_test_c ..................***Failed    0.01 sec
Software Radio Systems, Ltd: cannot connect to X server 
...
```

All eight of the tests fail. I've got X running, I can open xterm, so I don't think there's a problem w/ my DISPLAY variable. My guess is that debuild's sandbox is blocking/not passing through the X display. Should I be trying to tell debuild to pass through the X display, or should I be trying to tell it not to run the tests at all?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could tell debuild to retain the X display number by running `debuild -us -uc -eDISPLAY`. This solution doesn't however apply to most Debian packages, since they won't be built from an X environment (that includes not only official debian buildds, but also `autopkgtest`, `sbuild`, `pbuilder` environments). All in all, a Debian package should build successfully with just its build dependencies installed and nothing else.

The canonical solution to this is
- Build-depend on *xvfb*
- run your tests wrapped with `xvfb-run` like this (in *rules*):

```
override_dh_auto_test:
  xvfb-run dh_auto_test
```

For an example, [look here at salsa repository of gnome-settings-daemon](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-settings-daemon/-/blob/debian/master/debian/rules#L31).